# ASP.NET Core Identity GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync returning empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

App is .NET Core 2.1.

I'm implementing SMS two-factor auth in my site (already have app-based tfa), using Twilio, and everything's ready to go, with the minor problem of not being able to generate the token.

The following code is what I call when the user enters their mobile number to set up TFA in the first place. Just generating a code and texting it to them. But the call to `_userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync` is returning an empty string. Which, looking at the source code, it's hard-coded to do. Useful.

I was hoping to use that so I could use the same verification process I already have in place for my app-based tfa. So what function should I be using to generate tfa tokens to be sending to users? Or am I approaching this incorrectly?

EDIT: Just from my own digging, maybe I should be using the change phone number token for this initial setup. But then the question becomes, what should I use for the actual tfa process during login?

```
  [Authorize]
  [HttpPost("send-sms")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> SendSms(SMSModel input)
  {
     var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

     if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_smsOptions.Sid) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_smsOptions.Token)) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("phoneNumber", "SMS provider not set up.");
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
     }

     var code = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, _userManager.Options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider);
     var message = "Your one-time verification code is: " + code;

     TwilioClient.Init(_smsOptions.Sid, _smsOptions.Token);
     try {
        var result = await MessageResource.CreateAsync(
           to: new PhoneNumber(input.phone),
           from: new PhoneNumber(_smsOptions.From),
           body: message
        );
     } catch (Exception e) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("phoneNumber", e.Message);
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
     }

     return Ok();
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultPhoneProvider);`

You can get details from docs,
[how implement 2-factor auth in ASP.NET Core using sms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/2fa?view=aspnetcore-1.1)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes along later, I ended up figuring it out. I just searched through the .NET core library and found the token provider `PhoneNumberTokenProvider`. Just passed that into the generate function instead of the Authentication one, and that seems to be working great.

Now I just need to figure out if there's a built-in way to save which kind of tfa a user is set up with, or if I need to manage that myself...

Comment: hi can you please post a sample of how you solved this? I don't understand what you've done with PhoneNumberTokenProvider

Answer (score 0):

it's not work and return empty string when you try to get authenticator app token
you should to use under code to fix your problem

```
await _userManager.ResetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user);
var token = await _userManager.GetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user);
```

i use this code and work correctly
and you can see two factor authentication in identity source in [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2924ca229b3d6c91b7c9eded119b31dfd7aa1fef/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Manage/EnableAuthenticator.cshtml.cs)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).